# Is the movie TRON based from the movie Ra.One?

Tags: tron

Sometimes I see Western movies that look like a direct copy from the source of an Eastern movie.

As an example, is the American movie TRON a direct copy of the Ra.One?  Are there differences?

Comment: You could always see release dates of involved movies.. BTW, Indian movies and TV shows have great reputation of copying contents.. :) when it comes to sci-fi, they always do copy..

Comment: And, such things are popular in India. I wonder how you don't know it..

Comment: No. The Indian movie industry (which is known in India as 'Bollywood') has been plagiarizing western movies for decades. A large list of such copied movies here: http://www.bollywoodtrends.net/2009/04/bollywood-and-plagiarism-list-of.html or here: http://www.imdb.com/list/VJOuaN8R4cg/

Comment: Downvoters: This is not a bad *question* just one that is incorrect in it's assumptions. Stop using votes as a popularity contest.

Answer (score 13):

**No**

[Tron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron) is a Movie made in 1982, [Ra.One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra.One) is from 2011. There is another Tron movie, [Tron Legacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron%3a_Legacy) from 2010 which is the sequel of the original Tron. So if one copied the other, it's Ra.One.

As far as for the plot, there is some similarity, like entering the computer world, but the list of difference is to long to state it here.

Comment: In Ra.One, video game characters came out in real world..

Answer (score 1):

I live in India mate and the first thing you should know is Bollywood always copies from western movies. Ra-one was released here in October 2011.  Tron was released in July, 1982. Even if you were taliking about Tron Legacy, it was released in 2010.